# OpenVPN setup: Easy-RSA does not use current working directory

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am trying to set up a VPN server. But I fail at the first step -- easy-rsa.

Following the tutorial I installed openvpn and easyrsa on my server and copied the easy-rsa folder into my openvpn folder.
Now when I run `easyrsa clean-all` from my newly copied folder `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa`, I get an error

```
Easy-RSA error:

The OpenSSL config file cannot be found.
Expected location: /usr/bin/openssl-1.0.cnf
```

Now I noticed, when I run `easyrsa` without parameters to get the help I get this output

```
DIRECTORY STATUS (commands would take effect on these locations)
  EASYRSA: /usr/bin
  PKI:  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki
```

So easy-rsa accepts my current working directory for the ski but not for EASYRSA itself...
Is there a way to fix this?

I am running Arch Linux on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.
easy-rsa hat the `--vars`option which lets you point it to a specific vars file.
What worked for me now was

```
easyrsa --vars=./vars clean-all
```

And for all other commands I just added the `--vars=./vars` option and everything worked